# "A variety of" : verbal agreement

Tags: verb-agreement

> A plural verb is needed after **a/an (large, wide, etc.) variety of…**
>
> *A variety of reasons were given*.
>
> You can use a singular or a plural verb before it:

> *There **is/are** a wide variety of patterns to choose
> from.*
>
> https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/variety_1?q=variety

Why is the singular verb possible only if it appears "before" the verb?

Is this some general wider aspect of the English language?

Comment: The plural verb is required because of the plural **nouns** (_reasons, patterns,_ etc.) that they agree with, not because of the quantifiers in those phrases. And the position of the verb is irrelevant; the difference is about whether _there_-insertion has applied or not. Once again, a dictionary, especially a dictionary for language learners in another country, is not a good source for grammatical information.

Comment: https://oed.com/oed2/00275059

Answer (score -1):

It is easy to decide this issue if you first consider a short and very basic form of the sentence. "A variety was given." clearly has a singular subject. This leads naturally to "A variety (of reasons) was given". It is not like saying "Various reasons were given", which clearly has a plural subject.