# What are the correct choices in: [A  the] [variety  number] of [something  some things] [is  are]?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, singular-subject-and-verb

My English grammar teacher said that English has following rules:

> **A** variety/number of something **are**...

> **The** variety/number of something **is**...

We had the examples:

> A number of my colleagues are from Spain. The variety of monuments in Central Rome is shocking.

Is it the only right answer?

Comment: No; for "variety", it depends on the meaning: "A variety of foods is essential for a healthy diet."

Comment: @simple_asf In the number transparent sense "number" indicates an imprecise number: "A number of protesters **have** been arrested". But with the definite article it indicates a precise number, as in "The number of protesters **has** not been revealed", where the subject NP is singular by virtue of having singular non-transparent "number" as head.

Comment: Probably a duplicate: [a variety of – verbal agreement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/544749/a-variety-of-verbal-agreement). The verb agreement of 'a variety of [NP]' and 'the variety of [NP]' is covered at [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/variety).

Comment: Sorry; that looks like you were given at best incomplete and perhaps even bad examples.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment BillJ wrote:

> @simple_asf In the number transparent sense "number" indicates an imprecise number: "A number of protesters **have** been arrested". But with the definite article it indicates a precise number, as in "The number of protesters **has** not been revealed", where the subject NP is singular by virtue of having singular non-transparent "number" as head.

Comment: Dictionary.com says that the situation is very similar with 'a variety of' vs 'the variety of'.